# Buttons disappeared in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: menu, toolbar, adobe-illustrator

[These buttons have disappeared from the Free Transform Tool in Illustrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKEIh.png)

I've tried everywhere for the solution but still can't figure out where they are, I've already reset the toolbar but that doesn't work, I've also reset the workspace but still no luck? Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Did you re-install the tool?

Comment: Hi @JeroenHeier, sadly, nothing worked so I had to reformat my entire hard drive and re-install the OS to get it to work again properly.